# dynamically changing height of #container div in flexslider

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm working with flexslider and the container div has a background image that acts like a border set to the bottom of it. What I need to do is get the container div to be responsive like the actual flexslider div. So when you shrink the window from right to left, the height of the container div should change height, if that makes sense. Dimensions of the images are 1680x748. And currently the height of the container div is 805px and the width is set to 100%. So the width doesn't matter. Just need to change the height.

Answer (score 15):

Try This .

**smoothHeight: true,**

```
function _flexslider(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    smoothHeight: true,
    itemWidth: 280,
    itemMargin: 0,
    minItems: 1,
    maxItems: 1,
  });
}
```

Comment: Old. But that option does nothing from what I can see so far.

Answer (score 1):

The `.flexslider .slides img` selector has `max-width` set to 100% but add in `height: 748px;` in the CSS and it'll bring the slider up to that height which means all your images should fit.

```
.flexslider .slides img {
     max-width: 100%; 
     height: 748px; 
     display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into same issue, and what I notice is that I was cutting up my image width to the exact itemWidth value. The trick is to have the actual image be much bigger then that value. Because if the plugin cant scale the image bigger then is actual size. It can just decrease its width to keep is aspect ratio.